# Best practice to detect broken log sinks

Tags: serilog

I am trying to replace the in-house-written logger solution of one of my customers. Pretty much everything is straight forward, but i need to implement one sink that sends the logs to a custom log window that i cannot change (for now). It communicates using named pipes. this pipe may be broken or busy, so the current solution actually blocks on every log call - which I want to improve.

The question is what the best practice is when using serilog: whats the best way to tell serilog the sink is currently broken so it is not slowing down the system. Is throwing an exception enough?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Serilog itself doesn't know (or care) when a sink is broken or not, so I'm not sure I understand your goal.

Writing to a Serilog logger is supposed to be a safe operation, [by design](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Reliability), thus any exceptions that happen in your sink will automatically be caught by Serilog to make sure the app doesn't crash. Serilog will make sure these exceptions are written to the [`SelfLog`](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Debugging-and-Diagnostics#selflog) which developers can use to troubleshoot sink issues. [See an example here](https://github.com/augustoproiete/serilog-sinks-notepad#debugging-and-diagnostics).

Therefore, if your goal is to have a way that a developer can see when the sink experienced problems, the recommendation is to write error messages to the [`SelfLog`](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Debugging-and-Diagnostics#selflog) and throw your own exceptions from within your sink.

If you can detect from within your sink that the named pipe is not available without blocking, then just write to `SelfLog` and return/short-circuit without trying to write to it. It's really up to you to implement any kind of [resilience policy](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly#resilience-policies) from within your sink.

If your goal is to improve the blocking calls, you might want to consider making your sink asynchronous, with the messages sent on a separate thread, without blocking the main thread of the app.

Given you're implementing your own custom sink, an easy way to do that is to turn your sink into a [Periodic Batching sink](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-periodicbatching) and leverage the infrastructure it provides. Alternatively, you can use [Serilog.Sinks.Async](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-async) wrapper sink.

Comment: thanks. to explain: the old solution uses a background thread to read from a queue that was filled to infinity and ended in a system with no memory left.

Comment: The Async sink deals with this concern in general (see the readme - in general you should not run it in unlimited buffering mode)